# No Module named numpy in conda env

Tags: python, numpy, anaconda, conda

I have zero clue why my numpy is not getting recognized right now in conda env. I have all the packages installed but when I try to use numpy it says numpy Module not found. Because of that, pandas and sklearn also failing.

```
(ds) user-mbp:ibos_automation user$ python 
Python 3.7.3 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Mar 27 2019, 15:43:19) 
[Clang 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
```

This all started happening when I tried to install pdfminer.six using

```
pip install pdfminer.six
```

I also tried to roll back my conda env using revisions by doing

```
conda install --revision <prior_version>
```

but apparently it is throwing an error that some pytorch target lib is not available.

```
(ds) user-mbp:ibos_automation user$ conda install --revision 9

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are missing from the target environment:
  - pytorch::pytorch==1.3.1=py3.7_0
  - pytorch::torchvision==0.2.2=py_3
  - pytorch::captum==0.1.0=0
```

I have tried updating numpy by doing

```
conda update numpy
```

but apparently numpy is the latest version installed already

```
(ds) user-mbp:ibos_automation user$ conda update numpy
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done

# All requested packages already installed.
```

Can someone help how to fix this? I am apparently stuck because of this.

Comment: Please share the contents of the environment. Are you following proper procedure for using pip with Conda? See, for example: https://www.anaconda.com/using-pip-in-a-conda-environment/. Also, while I don't know how active it is, pdfminer.six is available from conda-forge: https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/pdfminer.six.

Answer (score 1):

First remove numpy from conda

```
conda remove numpy
```

Install it using pip

```
pip install numpy
```

Comment: Be careful when using pip with Conda. See, for example: https://www.anaconda.com/using-pip-in-a-conda-environment/.

Answer (score 0):

First checked

```
pip list
```

Please checked here  `numpy` library having or not
if having the numpy library then..
try this if you are using anaconda:

```
conda uninstall numpy
conda install numpy=1.18
```

or this if you are using python pip:

```
pip uninstall numpy
pip install numpy==1.18
```

Comment: Be careful when using pip with Conda. See, for example: https://www.anaconda.com/using-pip-in-a-conda-environment/.